# Is there a way to send POST data to another form and return the result of that form?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, post

I need to send form data to another page that will allow the user to do something in a form and return the result of that form back to the original page? Is this possible? I know it's not ideal, but the issue is that I need to make a "drop-in" solution that does not need to be integrated with other code. I know it's a very specific request and scenario.

I know how to send POST data that doesn't require any user input on the processing page. i.e. I can send POST data to 'calculate.php' which will do the math and send it back, but if I need additional user input on 'calculate.php', how can I still send it back?

An example of expected results would be:

> Page #1: User enters a number and presses submit to go to next page.
>
> Page #2: User enters a second number and presses submit to finish.
>
> Back to Page #1: User receives sum of both numbers.

Obviously, this is a really redundant thing to do, but I'm trying to simplify the problem as much as possible.

EDIT: There a few restrictions I forgot to add.

- Page #1 is not my application, I am developing Page #2 as a "drop-in" solution for Page #1. Essentially, I can only use Page #1 to call Page #2 and receive a response from it. The problem is that I need to be able to allow for user input on Page #2.
- I know I can post to Page #2 and then post to Page #1 again, but what if I need to maintain the state of Page #1. For example, if there's an open Web Socket connection.

Please note, I understand that this may be impossible or extremely difficult, but if I don't ask I'll never know right?

Comment: You could make use of sessions/cookies or you could just post forward the data then post it back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a few ways to do it.

1. Update a Database (or Data Store of some sort, depends on security needs) and have Page #1 listen for events from a separate page (on the same server as the database). Very similar to the way PayPal's Instant Payment Notification (IPN) works. I was actually able to set up server sent events with it as well.

Essentially, Page #1 sends data to Page #2 where the user will perform the function and then Page #2 will send POST data to a listener somewhere (either on the same server or Page #1's server), the listener will update a database and Page #1 will be listening or pulling to an event handler that will send an update once the database updates.

2. Use JavaScript Child/Parent Window functions. This is okay if Page #1 and Page #2 are on the same server, but can get messy and browsers have a lot of restrictions and it varies depending on browser.

Page #1 will open Page #2 in a child window, after the user performs a function, Page #2 will call a function that accepts the result data on Page #1.

Answer (score 0):

You want it with PHP or any other language. If you are running Php on server side then you can use Global variables like $_GET and $_POST.

> Page #1: Use Post/Get method to send data to second page.
>
> Page #2: Receive all fields' values using Globe variables ($_GET and $_POST). You can use these values as default values of form fields. Now submit this data to page 1 using post or get method.
>
> Back to Page #1: Here you will receive the data of first page from second page and newly posted data from page 2

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but what if I need to maintain a state on Page #1? For example,  what if I can't close the page on Page #1 because a Web Socket is open?

Comment: You state for the page 1 will be changed by page 2 after submitting data. one more thing you can also save your date in local storage then get it on page 1 and make required calculations to get sum

Comment: are you using PHP on backend and or any other language? May be React js on frontend!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should work:

1. Never leave the page - use AJAX / XMLHttpRequest to call out to other pages to process chunks of data
2. Do everything on page 1 using "postbacks" -- the form targets are the same page, there is a state variable like "stage=1", and you use JavaScript to add set hidden variables for any additional state that's needed.

   ... PHP state validation and processing for the different stages ...

   ... one or more blocks of HTML for the page  (PHP if / else can be used to choose between multiple page views) ...

Edit for added restrictions:

3. Have page 2 use postbacks or AJAX to collect the additional information

Comment: The problem with #1 is I need to be able to allow user input on the next page. The problem with #2 is I am not able to do much on Page #1, I don't have control over it. Essentially, I'm developing Page #2 as a "drop-in" solution, so I can't do anything with Page #1 except use it to call Page #2 and somehow accept a result. I need to be able to allow user input on Page #2 though.

Comment: See edit, do 1 or 2 on your page 2 instead of page 1.